# Samsung Galaxy S7 - How can I get the timer to sound when phone is in vibrate mode?

Tags: clock, vibration, volume, samsung-galaxy-s7

I usually keep my phone on vibrate.  Sometimes I need to set a timer, but when the time is up it only vibrates instead of sounding aloud.  I think it should behave like the alarm, which can sound aloud when the rest of the phone is on vibrate.  How can I make the timer do this?